# Revolution Slider and Craft CMS conflict on placeholders

Tags: templating

Revolution Slider is using Placeholders like this `{{param1}}`.
This is conflicting with Twig's variables.

Is there a workaround that Twig will ignore this for example?

Comment: https://www.evernote.com/l/AD-u0TD9jLRMj7O7n77IlJQvHzth6IhDUSQ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can stop Craft from parsing curly brace tags in your template code by using the Twig Verbatim tag. Here's an example:

```
{% verbatim %}{{ this.wont.be.touched }}{% endverbatim %}
```

You can use it to stop a single tag from being parsed, or encapulate an entire block of code on your page for multiple tags. Useful for languages like AngularJS that use the same double curly brace format.

More info at http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/verbatim.html

Comment: Perfect solution! It is working now :)

Comment: Nice! Always good to learn :)

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of.

From your example and image, I would suggest just swapping them out as I agree they look like placeholders, anyway.